# ogc:filter how to filter a number?

Tags: geoserver, sld, ogc

The below sld passing attribute5 having 3.09 or 5.56. But not 1690.98 or 10923.34 which is just opposite of what we need.
How to parse the string **attribute5** data as number here..

```
      <ogc:Filter>
     <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
       <ogc:PropertyName>attribute5</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
      </ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: The Filter specification shows something very similar to this in Example 14 (using ValueReference). Have you tried that? If so, what happened? If not, perhaps worth a try.

Comment: Please give the link...

Comment: Its the first hit for google for "OGC Filter" for me: http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter

Comment: You need to make attribute5 a double rather than a string. If attribute5 is a string it has to work this way

Comment: @iant Thanks buddy. Please give this as answer, It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set attribute5 as a String GeoServer will always use string comparisons if you want it to work as a number you will need to set attribute5 to double.

Comment: I replaced <ogc:PropertyName>attribute5</ogc:PropertyName> with <ogc:Function name="parseDouble">             <ogc:PropertyName>attribute5</ogc:PropertyName>
</ogc:Function> to get a working code... Thanks @iant